# How to set Flow player to auto re-size with the video resolution?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, playframework

Im using Flow Player with CMS that we could let users to add videos by logging in. As users could add videos with FLV format and different resolutions im having trouble to set a width and a height to the player.. 
Is there any way we could let it auto re-size with the video?
(And its opens with Fancy Box to play the video)
Please Help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
/*html*/
<a id="player"  style="display:block;width:/*Your static width*/;height:/*Your static height*/" href="Your video url">Video name</a>

/*script*/
$(document).ready(function(){

        if($('a#player').is(':visible')){ 
            flowplayer('player', '/plugins/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf',{

            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry but it didn't help but i was able to fix it by the functions here
http://flowplayer.org/forum/2/14168
But now its the fancy box re-size is the issue.. It wont get re-size with the player size to fit in. I think it because of an delay when re-sizing the player size.. Any solution for this please?